# Page changes when clicking a div link

Tags: html, css

I will explain my problem. 
For school I have to make a website, but it is not working how it should be.
I have a border made of divs around the screen, and the page in the middle. When I first open the page, everything is in place, but when I click on one of the nav items (#link) the page suddenly loses its margin top and left. So it goes outside of the borders. I pasted all the code in the snippet, as I believe it will be too much for a post.

To see the full page and problem, please copy the code in a file to open it in the browser itself. I used vw and vh because it want it to be the same on different screens. I will do the inside elements mostly with percentages

So my questions:

1. How do I prevent this from happening, and an example?
2. Is there a way to set #Home as the usual landing space? without adding #Home in the link (and without changing its position)?
3. And my last question regarding CSS animation, how do I add a transition so it looks like the page is scrolling to the #div.

```css
body{
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.wrapper{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container{
  width: 300vw;
  height: 200vh;
  background-image: url("../img/background.png");
  background-size: cover;
}
/* simple nav*/
ul{
  display: inline;
  z-index: 99;
  position: fixed;
}
ul li{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
}
ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*pages*/

.page{
  margin: 10vh 10vw;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
    transition: 2s;
}

#Interactive{
  background: blue;
  float: left;

}
#Graphical{
  float: left;

}
#Company{
  float: left;
}
#Conclusion{
  float: left;
}
#Home{
  float: left;
}
/*header borders*/
.borders{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 30;
}
.border-top{
height: 10vh;
width: 100vw;
top:0;
background: #007CFF;
}
.border-left{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 10vw;
  top: 0;
  background: #007CFF;
  position: absolute;
}
.border-right{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 10vw;
  top: 0;
  background: #007CFF;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -10vh;

}
.border-bottom{
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100vw;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #007CFF;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">


<ul>
  <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Interactive">Interactive</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Graphical">Graphical</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Company">Company</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Conclusion">Conclusion</a></li>
</ul>
</div>


<div class="borders">
<div class="border-top">
</div>
<div class="border-left">
</div>
<div class="border-right">
</div>
<div class="border-bottom">
</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container">
  <div id="Interactive" class="page">
  </div>
  <div id="Graphical"class="page">
  </div>
  <div id="Company"class="page">
  </div>
  <div id="conclusion"class="page">
  </div>
  <div id="home"class="page">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for thinking with me, any help is appreciated.
I didn't really know how to call this post, so the search for it was difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove this div

```
  #Interactive{
  background: blue;
  float: left;}
```

I think this only you are expecting.

Comment: Yes, because I need these 5 divs

Answer (score 0):

I have made changes to your `HTML` code and `CSS` code on the basis of what i thought you wanted to achieve. Below is the code.

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body{
    display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.header { 
    padding: 10px 50px;
}

ul li{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
.wrapper {
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding: 50px 150px;
}

.page{
    transition: 2s;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#Home{
    background-color: pink;
}
#Interactive{
  background: blue;
}
#Graphical{
    background-color: green;
}
#Company{
    background-color: yellow;
}
#Conclusion{
    background-color: orange;
}

<div class="header">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Interactive">Interactive</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Graphical">Graphical</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Company">Company</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Conclusion">Conclusion</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="Home" class="page">
  </div>
  <div id="Interactive" class="page">
  </div>
  <div id="Graphical" class="page">
  </div>
  <div id="Company" class="page">
  </div>
  <div id="Conclusion" class="page">
  </div>
</div>
```

1. If you want to use transition for smooth scrolling. Refer to
   [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/)
   article, you will have to use jQuery.
2. Also do not use fixed `width` or `height` until necessarily required.
3. Use `document.getElementById('Home').focus()` in `document.ready()` of `js` to bydefault show the Home Page.
4. Always focus on making responsive solutions with relative content rather than `absolute` content.

Let me know if you need more help :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want no 'scrolling' and that the div is one page wide in between those borders I made. From there out it should 'travel' to the other topic div. So if you make a sheet, you zoom in in one subject, and then you move on to the next when you hit the button. Don't really know how to explain it

Comment: What you are looking for is **Tabs** in HTML. Here is a simple tutorial of how to implement tabs using `js`. Follow [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp). I hope this is what you meant.